# react login and sign up pages with auth using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am building `Login` and `Signup` pages using react and auth by using firebase.

The problem is that after `successful login and signup`, the application is NOT navigating the user to `landing page`.

I think there is something wrong with my `handleLogin and handleSignup` methods but, I'm to pinpoint it out.

To Login: use -> email: test@gmail.com and password: 123456

Also, there are no errors in the console and I get 200 response from firebase.

This is `firebase.config.js`

```
import firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_KEY",
  authDomain: "login-and-push-notification.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "login-and-push-notification",
  storageBucket: "login-and-push-notification.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "84083076850",
  appId: "1:84083076850:web:3e9febc1341d8f7b036a6b",
};
// Initialize Firebase
const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default FB;
```

This is `Login.js`

```
const Login = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState("");
  const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState(false);

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  const clearErrors = () => {
    setEmailError("");
    setPasswordError("");
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fb.auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        console.log("user", user);
        props.navigation.push("/Landing");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
          case "auth/user-disabled":
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            setEmailError(error.message);
            break;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            setPasswordError(error.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };
  const handleSignup = () => {
    clearErrors();
    fb.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            setEmailError(error.message);
            break;
          case "auth/weak-password":
            setPasswordError(error.message);
            break;
        }
      });
  };

  const authListener = () => {
    fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        clearInputs();
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser("");
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="loginContainer">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          autoFocus
          required
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className="errorMsg">{emailError}</p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          required
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <p className="errorMsg">{passwordError}</p>
        <div className="btnContainer">
          {hasAccount ? (
            <span>
              <button onClick={handleLogin} type="submit">
                Sign In
              </button>
              <p>
                Don't have an account?
                <span onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)}>Sign up</span>
              </p>
            </span>
          ) : (
            <>
              <button onClick={handleSignup} type="submit">
                Sign Up
              </button>
              <p>
                Have an account?
                <span onClick={() => setHasAccount(!hasAccount)}>Sign in</span>
              </p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then I'm importing the `Login` component into the `Home` component and passing props.

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import Landing from "../Pages/Landing";

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.user ? <Landing {...props} /> : <Login {...props} />}</div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: What is the props you pass to your `Home` component ?

Comment: Are you using react rooter or something or am I missing something ?

Comment: @crg ` email={email}
            setEmail={setEmail}
            password={password}
            setPassword={setPassword}
            handleLogin={handleLogin}
            handleSignup={handleSignup}
            hasAccount={hasAccount}
            setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
            emailError={emailError}
            passwordError={passwordError}` these are the props that I intend to pass into `Home` component. No, I am not using react-router. I had seen a tutorial online and tried to follow the firebase docs and tried it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `authListener()` in `Login.js` is setting a state variable in the Login component, but it does not communicate the change of state back to the rest of the application.

One way to resolve this would be to move the `const [user, setUser] = useState()` from `Login.js` to `Home.js`, then pass `setUser` as a prop to `<Login>`.  That way, when the `onAuthStateChanged()` gets the user object, you set it in state at the `Home` level.

You'd additionally change the condition statement in `Home.js` to be:

```js
return (
    <div>{user ? <Landing {...props} /> : <Login {...props} />}</div>
  );
```

since `user` would now be a state variable in `Home.js`.

Once you have that working and are comfortable with it, you might consider moving all of your authentication handling into a pattern that leverages `useContext()`.  You would create an `AuthProvider` component.  There are several blogs on this topic, such as [this one](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/react-firebase-authentication-with-context-api-a770975f33cf)

Comment: In my `home component`, I am using `props.user` with the same intent. Also, if I `setUser` is being used throughout the login component. So, can't move that out.

Comment: `props.user` has to be coming from *somewhere* in your code.  Being a prop, it is just a parameter.  For it to have any effect on the app, you'd need to define it as a state variable *somewhere*.   I don't understand the comment about setUser.  You can pass setUser as a prop (i.e. coming into this component from somewhere else) and then use that prop value.  You could simply change `const [user, setUser] = useState()` to be `let {user, setUser} = props;`, and not change any other part of `Login.js`.  Of course, you'd then need to pass a `user` and a `setUser` prop into `<Login .... />`

Comment: [Try this gist](https://gist.github.com/gregfenton/331af6a2c434e1c9e70d1e37f2fca066).  For good measure, I threw in a handful of other code recommendations to fix some "React gotchas" you might otherwise run into.